# Save file from gnuradio to matlab or Gnu octave

Tags: python, matlab, octave, gnuradio

Ich want to ask how can i save the signal of the gnuradio to use it in matlab or gnuoctave.
The signal is ofdm signal from ofdm rx example in gnuradio in baseband.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GNU Radio File Format for the recorded samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041852/gnu-radio-file-format-for-the-recorded-samples)

Comment: also, FAQ: https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/FAQ#What_is_the_file_format_of_a_file_sink.3F_How_can_I_read_files_produced_by_a_file_sink.3F the mentioned scripts: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/tree/master/gr-utils/octave